Question about PDE involving D’Alembert's formula
I have seen this problem on a book, where it does not appear solved:
$$
\begin{cases}
u_{tt} - 9 u_{xx} = 0 \ &\text{in } (0,\pi) \times \Bbb{R}^+
\\[1mm] u(0, t) = u(\pi , t) = 0 \ &\text{for } t >0
\\[1mm] u(x,0) = \sin(x) \ & \text{for } x \in (0, \pi) \end{cases}
$$
The book says that, using D’Alembert formula, we can obtain more than one solution. If we denote $g(x):= u_t (x,0)$ , by applying the formula we have:
$$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{2} (\sin (x - 3t) + \sin(x+3t)) + \frac{1}{6} \int_{x-3t}^{x+3t} g(\omega) d \omega = \sin (x) \cos (3t) + \frac{1}{6} \int_{x-3t}^{x+3t} g(\omega) d \omega$$
Applying boundary values: $\int_{-3t}^{3t} g(\omega) d \omega = 0 = \int_{\pi - 3t}^{\pi + 3t} g(\omega) d \omega$
Obviously one solution is $u_0(x,t) = \sin (x) \cos (3t)$, but I am not seeing how to obtain other than that. The only thing I note is that every odd and $\pi$-periodic map should verify the requirement, but that brings us back to $u_0$, so any possible help to understand this would be very helpful.

If $g$ is odd and $\pi$-periodic, its Fourier series representation has the form
$$
g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\sin(nx), \tag{1}
$$
hence,
\begin{align}
\int_{x-3t}^{x+3t}g(\omega)\,d\omega
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\int_{x-3t}^{x+3t}\sin(n\omega)\,d\omega \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}\left[-\cos n(x+3t)+\cos n(x-3t)\right] \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2a_n}{n}\,\sin(nx)\sin(3nt). \tag{2}
\end{align}
Therefore, the general solution to the problem is
$$
u(x,t)=\sin(x)\cos(3t)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n\sin(nx)\sin(3nt). \tag{3}
$$
